# difference between ic_launcher, ic_launcher_foreground and ic_launcher_round

Tags: android-studio, icons

I am using Android Studio (v 3.4.1) to create Adaptive Launcher Icons. I am confused about the PNG files it is generating.

I used the Asset Studio to create Launcher Icons (Adaptive and Legacy). The process was simple enough. But I question if some of the output files are necessary.

The output consists of the following:

\release\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26

- ic_launcher.xml
- ic_launcher_round.xml

\release\res\mipmap-nndpi (for each pixel density)

- ic_launcher.png
- ic_launcher_foreground.png
- ic_launcher_round.png

\release\res\values\ic_launcher_background.xml

I think each \mipmap-nndpi folder only needs the [foreground & round].png files. When I created the icons manually, I did not create ic_launcher.png and didn't see a difference.

Is ic_launcher.png required for minimum Target SDK 28+?

Comment: Same question. Especially whats the difference between these two:
ic_launcher.xml , 
ic_launcher_round.xml

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at https://github.com/Viperusgit/AdaptiveIcons

- `ic_launcher_forground` is the name of the forgound image
- `ic_launcher` is the icon for older versions of android
- `ic_launcher_round` is the icon for older pixels

Comment: Does that mean ic_launcher_round is only used on Google Pixel devices? Not Samsung or any other manufacturers?